# Powershell hashtable Get_Item with backslashes

Tags: powershell

Can anyone explain why Get_Item of hashtable differs in behaviour to variables when writing to the host?

The following code:

```
$filePathA = "\\server\folderA"
$filePathB = "\\server\folderB"

$here = @'
FilePathA = \\server\folderA
FilePathB = \\server\folderB
'@

$hashtable = ConvertFrom-StringData -stringdata $here

Write-Host $filePathA
Write-Host $hashtable.Get_Item("FilePathA")
```

Outputs in Powershell ISE:

```
\\server\folderA
\server
olderA
```

Can this behaviour by Get_Item be prevented so that it behaves the same as the variable?

Thanks in advance,
Mike.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behaviour is not by Get_Item but by your input. The `ConvertFrom-StringData` assumes properly escaped data, [as per the documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849900.aspx):

> ConvertFrom-StringData supports escape character sequences that are
>   allowed by conventional machine translation tools. That is, the cmdlet
>   can interpret backslashes () as escape characters in the string data
>   by using the Regex.Unescape Method, instead of the Windows PowerShell
>   backtick character (`) that would normally signal the end of a line in
>   a script. Inside the here-string, the backtick character does not
>   work. You can also preserve a literal backslash in your results by
>   escaping it with a preceding backslash, like this: \. *Unescaped
>   backslash characters, such as those that are commonly used in file
>   paths, can render as illegal escape sequences* in your results.

Thus, the hashtable contains already garbage data:

```
$hashtable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
FilePathA                      \server♀olderA
FilePathB                      \server♀olderB
```

Proper escaping helps:

```
$here = @'
FilePathA = \\\\server\\folderA
FilePathB = \\\\server\\folderB
'@

$hashtable = ConvertFrom-StringData -stringdata $here
$hashtable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
FilePathA                      \\server\folderA
FilePathB                      \\server\folderB
```

In order to [avoid manual escaping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape(v=vs.110).aspx), `[Regex]::Escape()` can be used like so,

```
# Build similar a string
$here2 = $("FilePathA = {0}`nFilePathB = {1}" -f [Regex]::Escape("\\server\folderA"), [Regex]::Escape("\\server\folderB") )

$here2
FilePathA = \\\\server\\folderA
FilePathB = \\\\server\\folderB

$hashtable2 = ConvertFrom-StringData -stringdata $here2
$hashtable2

Name                           Value
----                           -----
FilePathA                      \\server\folderA
FilePathB                      \\server\folderB
```

Comment: Great thank you for responding - feel like an idiot for only skimming that documentation! My question is a contrived scenario to make it answerable - in reality the file paths are entered by the user at a command prompt as a single ';' delimited string (Chocolatey package params to be precise), I replace ';' with '`' so that a hashtable can be created and items referred to by key later in my script. I want to avoid the user having to escape backslashes - getting a feeling that that won't be possible with my current approach.

Comment: @Godders You can use `[Regex]::Escape()` to automagically escape backslashes. See the edit.

Answer (score 0):

If you read [ConvertFrom-StringData](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849900.aspx) documentation:

> ConvertFrom-StringData supports escape character sequences that are
>   allowed by conventional machine translation tools. That is, the cmdlet
>   can interpret backslashes () as escape characters in the string data
>   by using the Regex.Unescape Method, instead of the Windows PowerShell
>   backtick character (`) that would normally signal the end of a line in
>   a script. Inside the here-string, the backtick character does not
>   work. You can also preserve a literal backslash in your results by
>   escaping it with a preceding backslash, like this: \. Unescaped
>   backslash characters, such as those that are commonly used in file
>   paths, can render as illegal escape sequences in your results.

So your double backslash is seen as an escape sequence in one case and not the other.

Comment: Great thank you for your response - have added more detail to @vonPryz's answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old but you could also "reprocess" a raw string, note it does look odd:

```
$sStringToConvert = $sRawString -replace '\\', '\\'  
$hashP = ConvertFrom-StringData $sStringToConvert
```